# OnItemSelectedListener of a spinner to update edittext value

Tags: android, spinner

I created the class below :

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

    EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
edit.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

It results an error when I try to change the value of edittext in the other layout. I put below code in my main activity

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food, container, false);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)     rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
```

After I change the layout of the main activity, then I set the setOnItemSelectedListener for the spinner in that layout.

this is my food.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#d0dae9"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/foodcategory"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="@array/foodcategory1"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and below is the spinner item

```
<string-array name="foodcategory">
    <item>Drinks</item>
    <item>Meal</item>
    <item>Meat</item>
    <item>Snacks</item>
    <item>Breads</item>
    <item>Cakes</item>
    <item>Fruits</item>
    <item>Vegies</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
```

Please help me out..

Comment: Why are you creating the EditText inside the listener? That should go in your OnCreate... only the setText must be inside the listener.

Comment: please, show your food.xml and spinner item .xml from spinner adapter

Comment: I don't know how to change edittext, I've added the xmls

Comment: Thank you, I solved it..

Answer (score 0):

update your CustomOnItemSelectedListener class:

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final View rootView;

    public CustomOnItemSelectedListener(View root) {
        rootView = root;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edit.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

add rootView as argument to CustomOnItemSelectedListener constructor:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food, container, false);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)     rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener(rootView));
```

Comment: How can I have access to rootView from my listener class?